# Saving different image types with php and just renaming the target file path?

Tags: php, image

How much difference does it make if I want to save all uploaded images to my site as gif if I just do...

```
$target = 'images/avatars/' . md5($user['id']) . '.gif';
```

Rather than creating a gif in php copying the temp image and then saving? Will the browser still load the file? Will it still recognise the old file type? Does it really matter from a point of view where these images will never be downloaded purposelly through my site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can rename images to .gif and browsers will still display them as jpg even if you load them with a .gif extension.
It will still have a jpg filetype, just with a .gif extension. (Just tested this)